# Making an element fixed on scroll, when its not at the top of the page

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make an element get fixed when the window scrolls down to this element.

This issue I am facing is when it reaches that element, it suddenly jumps. I presume that this is because the element is suddenly becoming fixed and thus now no longer takes up any space within the document, thus the whole document jumps up about the height that the element was previously taking.

To fix this I have tried to insert another element of the same height, at the same time, but this doesnt seem to work either. I was wondering, what is the typical way of making an element fix in this manor?

This is the code to make it scroll

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($('#nav').length) {
        scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        pos = height-header
        if(scroll > pos) {
            $('#nav').css({'position':'fixed','top':header,'width':'100%'});
            if(!$('.empty_div').length) {
                $('body').after(empty_div);
            }
        } else {
            $('#nav').css({'position':'static','top':'0'});
            $(".empty_div").remove();
        }
    }
});
```

You can view my code at http://jsfiddle.net/op30ddxL/

Comment: Is the content before the *sticky nav* dynamic in height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the replacement element the same width and heigth, and you should insert it at the same position in the dom as the #nav element.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($('#nav').length) {
        scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        pos = height-header
        if(scroll > pos) {
            if(!$('.empty_div').length) {
                $('#nav').after(empty_div);
                $('.empty_div').css({'width':$('#nav').width(),'height':$('#nav').height()});
            }
            $('#nav').css({'position':'fixed','top':header,'width':'100%'});
        } else {
            $('#nav').css({'position':'static','top':'0'});
            $(".empty_div").remove();
        }
    }

});
```